# <RUFUS> What should i check in advanced format options ( Im trying to create a Bootable USB Stick)

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, rufus

What should i check in **advanced format options** ( Im trying to create a Bootable USB Stick

im very new to ubuntu so i would like some replies that are easy to understand and to follow. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please clarify a few things? From what operating system are you trying to make the Ubuntu disk? Which version of Rufus are you using? What advanced options are available to you?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to add additional advanced options if you want to flash Ubuntu into your USB stick.

Just select your flashdrive properly and then for example select your `ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso` you can use GPT if you have a recent computer or MBR for older ones.

You can follow this image from the Rufus website as an example

[image]

[Rufus website](https://rufus.ie/)